# Is Windows 7 throttling my CPU?

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, throttling

I am hoping someone with more experience in Windows 7 can help me out. I have written a php script that utilizes curl_multi to do some spidering. This script runs on an install of WAMP. I originally had this script running on a Windows XP machine but decided to build a faster computer so I could utilize more threads. (The old machine was fairly slow and would max out CPU usage pretty quickly).

I have put together a Windows 7 box with a 6 core AMD 1090T, 16GB of ram and an SSD drive. The new machine is fast and my script WAS running exponentially faster. I was able to dial up the number of threads I was using and get the CPU usage up to about 90% across all cores.

After about an hour or so of running, the CPU usage dropped down to about 16% (every now and then it spikes up to 50%) and the script began running much slower.

I have spent the last 2 days searching the internet for an answer. I have tried disabling my firewall, changing power save modes in the bios, changing power management settings in Windows 7, editing throttling settings in the registry. Somewhere I am missing something. Is the CPU usage being throttled? Are the threads created by this script being throttled? How come it ran fine for that first hour?

Before I uninstall Windows and go with Ubuntu, I am hoping someone has an answer.

Comment: What is the CPU percent usage at this time (when your script is using only 16%)?

Comment: 16% is the CPU usage, sorry if that was unclear in my post.

Comment: Have you tried running the PHP script outside of WAMP?

Comment: I have run it on my Centos server and did not experience the same problem. On Windows, I have only tried it in WAMP. The XP machine also used WAMP and did not slow down.

Comment: ~16% just happens to be ~100% /6 Cores, which would be full load for a single threaded application. (just spread across the 6 cores or not).  The first thing i would do is run 6X prime (cpu testing) the same way and see if it holds full load. If it does not did threads stop.  I dont see anything that confirms that the threads were all still running, and it sounds most like One single hard working thread (16), and other stuff (50)

Comment: I should also add that I had now tested my computer with Prime95 and was able to get the CPU usage up to 100%. Seems this throttling is targeted at my script or WAMP.

Comment: Windows does not throttle, unless there is something that is of higher priority taking its place. I think you have an error  in your script that as @Psycogeek said, makes it unsuitable for threading after a while.

Comment: Hi Psycogeek, I had the same thought regarding the 16%. 16% is the average but it does jump around, sometimes as high as 50%. If I run my script with a single thread, I get one CPU maxing out at 100% with an average of 16% across the boards. Using multiple threads (say 50), I was getting 90-100% usage across all CPUs. I didn't change anything with the script but for some reason, it slowed down.

Comment: win7 Luvs to do the HANG thing, on my favorite older apps, I found out the old HungAppTime registry entry can "fix" it being somewhat overreactionary to a working program, that may not follow all the rules (as if any of them do).   So a theory is, it did that "not responding" thing to some of the threads?

Comment: @soandos I will look at my code again but I don't think that is the problem. Restarting Windows or my script does not solve the problem. That first hour is the only time I got it to run quickly. Since then it is slow, even after a restart. It runs fine for hours on XP and Unix.

Comment: **Restarting Windows or my script does not solve the problem.** then what are the temps?  will you ever eventually tell us what the script is doing? :-)

Comment: @Psycogeek, the script is going out to different websites and gathering information. It is based on the code by Josh Frasier that uses multi_curl without blocking (http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/). Per Core Temp 1.0, my CPU temp is 38C min, 41C max. Thank you everyone for taking the time to help me out with this. It is VERY much appreciated.

Comment: The restarting not fixing anything has me stumped, code beyond me. That just leaves, Watching, resource monitor, or process monitor, and thread watching, and check for Leaks, and drive space and activity, roboting, is files, and lots of small ones or oversized and sometimes problematic databases? Quick disk speed check, defrag

Comment: Thanks Psychogeek for the input. I think I will spend sometime watching the resource monitor and see if I can catch anything. I just did some checks on on my database and everything is running as expected. The drive is SSD (500Mbs) and seems to be working fast per HD Speed. Hopefully I will catch something!

Comment: Windows does some weird things.  I believe it attempts to determine whether a given application is "foreground" or "background", and that determination is "sticky".  Try, eg, going into SystemProperties/Advanced/Performance Settings/Advanced and clicking the "best performance of background services" button.